# windows phone app with facebook login coded in html5

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, facebook-login

Did anyone develop a windows phone html5 app, with facebook login? 
I tried facebook plugin for cordova, but it works only for android.

I want to know if there is a solution to build a Windows Phone 8 html5 app and integrate it with facebook?

I've already developed an html5 app for android and the integration with facebook works fine. I used the cordova plugin 'facebookConenctPlugin'.

Now I'd like send it to windows phone store, but the facebook login doesn't work on Windows Phone 8

Comment: Did you tried with the Javascript SDK? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @crafter my question is there is a solution to build a wp8 html5 app and integrate it with facebook? I've already develped an html5  app for android and the integration with facebook works fine. I used the cordova plugin 'facebookConenctPlugin', now I'd like send it to windows phone store, but the facebook login doesn't work on wp8

Comment: I've copied this into the post. Now it reads better. Can you explain what you mean by "the facebook login doesn't work". This could mean anything. Give example of your code and any errors that show. @LoveMetal pointed to the SDK - what is your response?

Answer (score 2):

Try Winjs sdk for facebook login https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-winjs-sdk it works in the given documentation during login process use 
 Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAndContinue instead of Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync as it isn’t implemented on Windows Phone 8.1.
This will launch the ui asking permission.After the users logs in you will get the response from the facebook and you handle it in your activation handler when your app starts up again like so:

app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {

```
    if (args.detail.kind ==      activation.ActivationKind.webAuthenticationBrokerContinuation) {
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = args.detail.webAuthenticationResult.responseData;
        var qs = extractQuerystring(parser.hash.substr(1).split('&'));
        if (qs.error) {
            console.log('error: ' + qs.error + ' : ' +qs.error_description);
            return;
        }

        FB.options({ accessToken: qs.access_token });
        FB.api("/me", function (res) {
            if (!res || res.error) {
                console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
                return;
            }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

At the end I used phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser js (https://github.com/caiovaccaro/phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser), and it works for me. I put it in my www/js and referenced in my index.html.  I had to integrate also the cordova plugin org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.